# error: could not find `sui` in https://github.com/MystenLabs/sui.git?branch=devnet with version `*`

Tags: git, github, rust-cargo, sui

When trying to install sui binaries using

```
cargo install --locked --git https://github.com/MystenLabs/sui.git --branch devnet sui
```

as suggested by the official [docs](https://github.com/sui-foundation/sui-move-intro-course/blob/main/unit-one/lessons/1_set_up_environment.md#install-sui-binaries-locally),

gives the below error

```
Updating git repository `https://github.com/MystenLabs/sui.git` 
error: could not find `sui` in https://github.com/MystenLabs/sui.git?branch=devnet with version `*`
```

What could be the possible reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the below command which includes the tag to install it

```
cargo install --locked --git https://github.com/MystenLabs/sui.git --branch devnet --tag devnet-<version> sui
```

where you can replace version as required (e.g v1.3.0)

Comment: Stale, devnet is now 1.3.0. Perhaps you should generalize